# Adding a Google CSE bar to a New Tab Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I've been trying to add a Google Custom Search Engine bar to my new tab extension, but I haven't had much luck. The error I get in the console is:

> Refused to load the script 'http://cse.google.com/cse...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com".

I've included in my manifest the content security policy:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
```

and I am running the script on an external javascript file (background.js) that I also have marked in my manifest:

```
"background": {
   "persistent": false,
   "scripts": [ "script/background.js" ]
},
```

I'd like to also include an iframe that gets the results, but I haven't quite made it that far. I don't think this will help but here is the script (excluding my auth key):

```
(function() {
var cx = 'auth key'
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

and on the new tab page I've included:

```
</div>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
<div>
```

background.js is called in the header of the document under jquery and flowtype.js - I've also tried putting the script into a document.ready function inside of an app.js page that I load right before the closing  tag.

Comment: Um. You are aware of the limitations of CSE, right? 100 searches per day, total.

Comment: ... How does momentum (google chrome extension) use theirs then? They have the same setup as far as I can tell?

Comment: Why do you think they use CSE? I'd suppose they just make a custom form that redirects to normal Google search.

Comment: That might be what they are doing, I might have misinterpreted it - it redirects the search query to search.momentum.com, but the iframe that pops up seems to be CSE since it has the watermark..

Comment: Well, if they have it on a site, it's possibly fine. But you can't just embed CSE to an extension, and using the API has a limitation of 100/day free, 10000/day paid (across all users).

Comment: damn. I believe that google and pretty much every other popular website I'd like to iframe (facebook,twiiter,etc.) into the extension blocks it. Is there any way around that?

Comment: No. For a lot of reasons, from brand identity to security to ad revenue.

Comment: alright can you explain how the website 2ez.gg does it then?

Comment: No? I don't even want to look at it. This conversation veers very much off-topic.

Comment: Well thank you for confirming what I hoped was not the case - you've been very good at that in all of my posts :)